# Restore files on git that were deleted when a branch was deleted

Tags: git, version-control

I know there are a lot of similar questions on SO about this topic, so I apologize if this is a duplicate.  However, I *think* this case is unique compared to the others I've seen.

I had some local files in my repo directory which I did not realize were untracked.  I then created a new local branch, made a significant change to the directory structure, and did a git add of the entire directory and committed (this was the most convenient way I could think of to commit the restructure).

I later changed my mind about the restructure, so I deleted the entire branch without merging it, but this unfortunately deleted all the previously untracked files which weren't present in any of the other branches.

I was able to find commits from the deleted branch and check them out, but the deleted files are nowhere to be found.  I've also tried using:

```
 git log -- <filepath>
```

Unfortunately that's not showing anything either.  These files were *definitely* deleted when the branch was deleted, so they must have been tracked by git at some point, but I can't find anything at all.

Comment: How do you know that they were committed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file was truly committed, and your reflog was not deleted (by default - 30 days), you should be able to see which commits affected a particular set of files or directories by one the following:

```
git reflog -- path/to/some/file.txt
git reflog -- path/to/some/file.txt path/to/another/file.txt
git reflog -- path/to/some/directory
git reflog -- */some.file
```

If it does not show up, then it means that it was never added to a commit.

If it was possibly stashed, then the following command can help:

```
git stash list -- path/to/some/file.txt
```

Comment: I guess I really never did commit the files, though that leaves me in the dark as to how they were deleted.  It was about 14 different sub-directories spread across 10 other directories within my repo, so I certainly didn't delete them by hand accidentally.  Anyway, I believe if I _had_ committed them then your answer would have solved the problem, so thanks anyway!

Comment: @user3174484 Well, I guess that it is still useful to know that you cannot recover them Git, instead of agonizing over it. Is it possible, that you used `git clean`?